# Multiple viewers on one page showing broken panorama

Tags: javascript, three.js, photosphere, photosphereviewer

I am not sure if this is a bug or an issue with my code but I am having trouble understand this error.

This demo URL has about 19 viewers: https://jsfiddle.net/mtran21/q87gt1es/16

If you click on any modal of the first row, it shows this
[image]

If you click on any of them below that then they are working just fine.

So I removed some of them, I keep only the first 2 rows of the modals. Then they are working just fine and here it the demo for only about 6 modals https://jsfiddle.net/mtran21/nc9Ltzjm/7/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#" class="thumb" id="thumb131155"><img src="https://placehold.co/200x150" alt=""></a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>ASB 101</h3>

          <p><strong>Capacity: 48</strong></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal:131155 -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="131155" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="131155" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" id="close131155">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ASB 101</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="panorama-margin" id="photosphere131155" style="width: 100%; height: 50vh;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info">
                  <div class="info-cell">
                    <p class="large">Capacity: 48</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info">
                  <a class="btn btn-default btn-wide" href="#?ID=151168">Classroom Technology</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-wide">Schedule</a></div>
              </div> <!-- end footer row -->
            </div> <!-- end modal-footer -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Modal: 131155 -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const viewer131155 = new PhotoSphereViewer.Viewer({
        container: 'photosphere131155',
        panorama: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552288092-76e7d732366c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2171&q=80',
        caption: 'ASB 101',
        navbar: [
          'zoom',
          'move',
          'caption',
          'fullscreen',
        ],
      });
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#thumb131155").click(function() {
          $("#131155").modal("show");
        });
        $("#close131155").click(function() {
          $("#131155").modal("hide");
          viewer131155.destroy();
        });
      });

    </script>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#" class="thumb" id="thumb131156"><img src="https://placehold.co/200x150" alt=""></a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>ASB 103</h3>

          <p><strong>Capacity: 48</strong></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal:131156 -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="131156" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="131156" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" id="close131156">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ASB 103</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="panorama-margin" id="photosphere131156" style="width: 100%; height: 50vh;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info">
                  <div class="info-cell">
                    <p class="large">Capacity: 48</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info">
                  <a class="btn btn-default btn-wide" href="#?ID=151168">Classroom Technology</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-wide">Schedule</a></div>
              </div> <!-- end footer row -->
            </div> <!-- end modal-footer -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Modal: 131156 -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const viewer131156 = new PhotoSphereViewer.Viewer({
        container: 'photosphere131156',
        panorama: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584184087921-b397a56c13c3?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1971&q=80',
        caption: 'ASB 103',
        navbar: [
          'zoom',
          'move',
          'caption',
          'fullscreen',
        ],
      });
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#thumb131156").click(function() {
          $("#131156").modal("show");
        });
        $("#close131156").click(function() {
          $("#131156").modal("hide");
        });
      });

    </script>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#" class="thumb" id="thumb131158"><img src="https://placehold.co/200x150" alt=""></a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>ASB 104</h3>

          <p><strong>Capacity: 48</strong></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal:131158 -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="131158" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="131158" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" id="close131158">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ASB 104</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="panorama-margin" id="photosphere131158" style="width: 100%; height: 50vh;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info">
                  <div class="info-cell">
                    <p class="large">Capacity: 48</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info">
                  <a class="btn btn-default btn-wide" href="#?ID=151168">Classroom Technology</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-wide">Schedule</a></div>
              </div> <!-- end footer row -->
            </div> <!-- end modal-footer -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Modal: 131158 -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const viewer131158 = new PhotoSphereViewer.Viewer({
        container: 'photosphere131158',
        panorama: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1617186929168-dd54edc6a3a2?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2045&q=80',
        caption: 'ASB 104',
        navbar: [
          'zoom',
          'move',
          'caption',
          'fullscreen',
        ],
      });
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#thumb131158").click(function() {
          $("#131158").modal("show");
        });
        $("#close131158").click(function() {
          $("#131158").modal("hide");
        });
      });

    </script>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#" class="thumb" id="thumb131160"><img src="https://placehold.co/200x150" alt=""></a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>ASB 105</h3>

          <p><strong>Capacity: 40</strong></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal:131160 -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="131160" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="131160" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" id="close131160">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ASB 105</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="panorama-margin" id="photosphere131160" style="width: 100%; height: 50vh;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info">
                  <div class="info-cell">
                    <p class="large">Capacity: 40</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info">
                  <a class="btn btn-default btn-wide" href="#?ID=151168">Classroom Technology</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-wide">Schedule</a></div>
              </div> <!-- end footer row -->
            </div> <!-- end modal-footer -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Modal: 131160 -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const viewer131160 = new PhotoSphereViewer.Viewer({
        container: 'photosphere131160',
        panorama: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1596988574375-6b01bfa312a2?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1884&q=80',
        caption: 'ASB 105',
        navbar: [
          'zoom',
          'move',
          'caption',
          'fullscreen',
        ],
      });
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#thumb131160").click(function() {
          $("#131160").modal("show");
        });
        $("#close131160").click(function() {
          $("#131160").modal("hide");
        });
      });

    </script>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#" class="thumb" id="thumb131162"><img src="https://placehold.co/200x150" alt=""></a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>ASB 201</h3>

          <p><strong>Capacity: 48</strong></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal:131162 -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="131162" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="131162" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" id="close131162">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ASB 201</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="panorama-margin" id="photosphere131162" style="width: 100%; height: 50vh;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info">
                  <div class="info-cell">
                    <p class="large">Capacity: 48</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info">
                  <a class="btn btn-default btn-wide" href="#?ID=151168">Classroom Technology</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-wide">Schedule</a></div>
              </div> <!-- end footer row -->
            </div> <!-- end modal-footer -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Modal: 131162 -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const viewer131162 = new PhotoSphereViewer.Viewer({
        container: 'photosphere131162',
        panorama: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597234496463-d0a82e73b3a6?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1979&q=80',
        caption: 'ASB 201',
        navbar: [
          'zoom',
          'move',
          'caption',
          'fullscreen',
        ],
      });
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#thumb131162").click(function() {
          $("#131162").modal("show");
        });
        $("#close131162").click(function() {
          $("#131162").modal("hide");
        });
      });

    </script>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#" class="thumb" id="thumb131165"><img src="https://placehold.co/200x150" alt=""></a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>ASB 202</h3>

          <p><strong>Capacity: 48</strong></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal:131165 -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="131165" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="131165" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" id="close131165">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ASB 202</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="panorama-margin" id="photosphere131165" style="width: 100%; height: 50vh;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info">
                  <div class="info-cell">
                    <p class="large">Capacity: 48</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info">
                  <a class="btn btn-default btn-wide" href="#?ID=151168">Classroom Technology</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 room-info"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-wide">Schedule</a></div>
              </div> <!-- end footer row -->
            </div> <!-- end modal-footer -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Modal: 131165 -->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const viewer131165 = new PhotoSphereViewer.Viewer({
        container: 'photosphere131165',
        panorama: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1604168612704-edf7120be425?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2066&q=80',
        caption: 'ASB 202',
        navbar: [
          'zoom',
          'move',
          'caption',
          'fullscreen',
        ],
      });
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#thumb131165").click(function() {
          $("#131165").modal("show");
        });
        $("#close131165").click(function() {
          $("#131165").modal("hide");
        });
      });

    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

This bug is on Chrome and Edge. So far it is working with Firefox and Safari.

I hope you could help me find out what the problem and how to fix it.

Thank you